# Why is my object call passing arguments when I am intending not?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am learning python 2.7 and am writing a text-adventure game (likened to Zork) to practice with. I decided to test out writing it in a modular way seeing as there will be a lot of functions that can be separated into different files for organization and clarity.

Using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7, I made a solution that comprises 3 files: MainGame.py, Session.py and Verbs.py.

- MainGame.py is the main python file for running the game.
- Session.py is a class file that it's instances store the players information.
- Verbs.py is used for the functions that analyze the players input.

What is displayed here is just to test if I can pass an object to the functions I need to analyze the data of the player.

Main.py

```
from Session import Session
from verbs import showX

s = Session()

showX(s)
```

Session.py

```
class Session(object):
    def __init__(self):
        x = 5

    def getX():
        return x
```

Verbs.py

```
def showX(s):
    print s.getX()
```

When I go to run this I get:

```
TypeError was unhandled by user code

getX() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

When I invoke the getX method inside showX I am expecting not to pass it anything, yet I am.

My question is; what am I passing it? What is wrong with this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class methods always get an extra parameter added at the beginning of the call, to signify the object the method was called on. That's why they should always have a `self` parameter at the start.

You probably want `Session.py` to look like this:

```
class Session(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

    def getX(self):
        return self.x
```